# ".to.be.sorted()" assertion does not work with Cypress

Tags: cypress, chai

Hi I am a newbie in cypress. Please help: Why can't I generate the text of the list to an array? I tried to use invoke but it is causing the text not to be in an array. I have tried the following already.

```
it('can sort by aToz', () => {
  cy.get('h4.card-title')
  .then($titles => {
    const title = $titles
      .toArray()
      .map($el => $el.innerText)
    // assertion comes from chai-sorted
    expect(title).to.be.sorted()
  })
})


  it('checks sort by A to Z', () => {
    cy.get('#sort').select('A to Z')
    cy.wait(4000)
    function getTableData() {
        let cellContents = [];
        return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
          cy.get('h4.card-title')
            .each(($el, $index) => {
                cellContents.push($el.text());

             }) .then(() => resolve(cellContents))
            })
      }
      getTableData().then(cellContents => {
        expect(cellContents).to.be.sorted()
      })
```

but both will just yield this:

```
(12) [h4.card-title, h4.card-title, h4.card-title, h4.card-title, h4.card-title, h4.card-title, h4.card-title, h4.card-title, h4.card-title, h4.card-title, h4.card-title, h4.card-title]
0: h4.card-title
1: h4.card-title
2: h4.card-title
3: h4.card-title
4: h4.card-title
5: h4.card-title
6: h4.card-title
7: h4.card-title
8: h4.card-title
9: h4.card-title
10: h4.card-title
11: h4.card-title
length: 12
__proto__: Array(0)
```

[image: Here is my HTML]

It logs correctly. but why does it have this error?

`Invalid Chai property: sorted`

Comment: What does `cy.log(title)` print? I tried your first code snippet and it works as expected.

Comment: It logs correctly. but why does it have this error? Invalid Chai property: sorted. Did you mean "nested"? @Sree.Bh

Comment: The reason is `chai-sorted` is not implicitly provided by cypress. You need to add and do the configuration explicitly.

Comment: it works!!! Thank you @Sree.Bh. I used the npm install chai-sorted

Comment: I have added an answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [chai-sorted](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-sorted/) dependency is not implicitly provided by Cypress.

To use `chai-sorted`, you need to:

- `npm i chai-sorted`
- In `support/index.js` add:

  ```
  const chaiSorted = require('chai-sorted');
  chai.use(chaiSorted);
  ```

The 'chai-sorted' is ready to use: `expect(<list of string>).to.be.sorted()`